# How to get FileHelpers.Net to invoke AfterWrite Event when using MultiRecordEngine?

Tags: c#, filehelpers

How can I get the FileHelpers.Net `MultiRecordEngine` to invoke its `AfterWriteRecord` and/or `BeforeWriteRecord` event when a record is written? It appears this event is never invoked. The end goal is to obtain the actual string (line) written into the file which is usually provided by the `FileHelpers.Events.AfterWriteEventArgs` in the `AfterWriteRecord` event.

I am using FileHelpers.Net version 3.1.5

**Note:** In the code below I can change `MultiRecordEngine` to `FileHelperAsyncEngine` (and limit the constructor to a single type) and the events are invoked without issue.

Here is the basic setup:

```
    using (MultiRecordEngine engine = new MultiRecordEngine(
    typeof(HeaderRecord),
    typeof(RecordSegment),
    typeof(TrailerRecord)))
    {
        engine.AfterWriteRecord += Engine_AfterWriteRecord;
        engine.BeforeWriteRecord += Engine_BeforeWriteRecord;

        HeaderRecord header = new HeaderRecord();
        engine.WriteNext(header);

     }
```

And these events are never invoked when `WriteNext` is called

```
    private void Engine_BeforeWriteRecord(EngineBase engine, FileHelpers.Events.BeforeWriteEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        // not invoked when using MultiRecordEngine
    }

    private void Engine_AfterWriteRecord(EngineBase engine, FileHelpers.Events.AfterWriteEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        // not invoked when using MultiRecordEngine
        // I want e.RecordLine!
    }
```

I appreciate any insights!

Answer (score 1):

I will answer my own question in case it helps someone else.

In looking through the FileHelpers.Net sourcecode for the **MultiRecordEngine** class, it appears that **WriteNext** does not invoke any events.

However...

The **MultiRecordEngine.WriteStream(TextWriter writer, IEnumerable records)** method does invoke events. In my case, I am using a stream based on a **TextWriter** so it was fairly simple to call this method instead of the more convenient **WriteNext** method.  Doing so, the events are invoked properly.

Something like the following:

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(myStream);
...
...
HeaderRecord header = new HeaderRecord();
//engine.WriteNext(header);
engine.WriteStream(tw, new List<HeaderRecord>() { header });
```

I am not sure if this behavior (of **WriteNext** not invoking events) is by design or by accident. I personally would consider it to be a bug, since there appears to be no limitation preventing these events from being invoked, there is no documentation to the contrary, and it is not consistent with the other FileHelper classes like **FileHelperAsyncEngine**.